# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, typeerror

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'
```

forms.py

```
class StudentMarksheetform2(forms.Form):
    subject_code=(
        (1,'CS101'),
        (2,'CS102'),
        (3,'CS103'),
        (4,'CS104'),
        (5,'CS105'),
        (6,'CS106')
    )
    code_title=forms.IntegerField(choices=subject_code,default='1')

    class Meta():
        model=StudentMarksheetdata2
        fields=['code_title']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a form. A form deals with interacting with the user. An `IntegerField` of `forms` has no `choices`. After all the `IntegerField` of models deals with how we *store* data in the database.

You can use a [**`TypedChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#typedchoicefield) for this:

```
class StudentMarksheetform2(forms.Form):
    SUBJECT_CODE = (
        (1,'CS101'),
        (2,'CS102'),
        (3,'CS103'),
        (4,'CS104'),
        (5,'CS105'),
        (6,'CS106')
    )

    code_title=forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=SUBJECT_CODE, coerce=int, initial=1)
    
    class Meta:
        model=StudentMarksheetdata2
        fields=['code_title']
```

Answer (score 0):

**"forms.IntegerField()"** doesn't have **"choices" and "default" options** different from **"models.IntegerField()"** which has **"choices" and "default" options**.

So, to have **Dropdown Single Select Box** using **the fields(classes) from "django.forms"**, use **"ChoiceField"** or **"TypedChoiceField"** which have **"choices" and "initial" options** as shown below. ***"initial" option** is equivalent to **"default" option**:

**"ChoiceField"**:

```py
# "forms.py"

from django import forms

class StudentMarksheetform2(forms.Form):
    
    # ...
    
    code_title=forms.ChoiceField(choices=SUBJECT_CODE, initial=1)
    
    # ...
```

**"TypedChoiceField"**:

```py
# "forms.py"

from django import forms

class StudentMarksheetform2(forms.Form):
    
    # ...
    
    code_title=forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=SUBJECT_CODE, initial=1)
    
    # ...
```